# generate temporary filename with .ico extension on windows

Tags: c, winapi

I wish to generate a temporary filename that ends with the extension `.ico` using the windows C API.

I have tried using GetTempFileName but then I cannot control the extension.

Comment: Why not use `GetTempFileName` and then concatenate `".ico"` to it?

Comment: @DYZ: Because that breaks why you'd use `GetTempFileName` in the first place (i.e. the returned file name is no longer guaranteed to be unique).

Comment: I'm passing the file later to LoadImage, which seems to use the extension to decide what format the file is in. That's why I need the extension to be `.ico`.

Comment: That doesn't sound very plausible. Pass IMAGE_ICON.

Answer (score 2):

The only reasons why you'd want to use [GetTempFileName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364991.aspx) is, because it guarantees to produce a unique file name. Appending an arbitrary extension breaks that invariant, so that is not a solution.

So you need a solution that produces a unique file name. Using the string representation of a GUID is a common way to get that:

```
std::wstring GetUniqueFileName( const std::wstring& extension = std::wstring() ) {
    GUID guid{ 0 };
    _com_util::CheckError( ::CoCreateGuid( &guid ) );
    wchar_t buffer[39];
    if ( !::StringFromGUID2( guid, buffer, sizeof( buffer ) / sizeof( *buffer ) ) ) {
        throw std::runtime_error( "StringFromGUID2() failed." );
    }
    std::wstring retVal{ buffer };
    retVal += extension;
    return retVal;
}
```

Comment: @alk: I'm pretty sure this was changed in between me starting to answer the question, and publishing the answer. If you do need a C solution, you know which API calls to use.